# Wrong adjustment created at type = Invoice level where amount is lessthan total invoice amount

Tags: oracle

User creates an adjustment of `type = INVOICE` which not equal to the total amount of invoice but some how user manage to save the adjustment, Unlike in test instance application is not allowing us to save the adjustment beacase `type=INVOICE` amount is less the the total amount of invoice.

Comment: Error message while replicating the same issue in test instance: AR-11503: invoice type adjustment must make the balance due zero.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). what you have tried, what are the minimal data and what is expected output?

Comment: We have one entry in AR_ADJUSTMENTS table that got create after this type =INVOICE adjusted by user now its creating variace in GL that amount.

Comment: GL_POSTED_DATE = null and POSTABLE = N columns in AR_ADJUSTMENTS table for that entry.